# Cost Distance Analysis QGIS with Vector files

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, distance, cost-path

I am trying to calculate the costpath from a location (polygon) to a point dataset using QGIS. I found two tools (r.cost.raster & accumulated cost (isotropic)), which both would work, if I would use only raster datasets. Unfortunatly one of my Datasets is a polygon so I can't use these tools. Any ideas how I could work around this problem?

Comment: Why don't you preliminarily convert your shapefiles to rasters and then convert the outputs to shapefiles again? As it is currently written, your question is too broad because it doesn't describe a specific problem (so, my question could be wrong because it doesn't refer to a specific situation).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use PyQGIS for that, here is an example:

```
# define the point 
pt = QgsPoint(572470.29638,191838.143182) 
pt =  QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt)

# get the active polygon 
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() 
polygon = layer.getFeatures().next() 
geom = polygon.geometry()

# do the business     
distanceToPolygon = QgsGeometry.distance(pt, geom) 
print distanceToPolygon
```